# Java my method return statement isn't breaking method

Tags: java

```
public int at(int i) {
    BNode current = storage.root;
    return traverse(i, current);
}

public int traverse (int i, BNode root){ // Each child of a tree is a root of its subtree.
  if (root.left != null) {
     traverse(i, root.left);
  }
  if (root.right != null) {
     traverse(i, root.right);
  }
  if(root.index == i) {
     System.out.println(root.value);
     return 1;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

This is just a part of the code and when i run, System.out.println(root.value) line executes properly and prints the value but it doesn't return 1 instead it returns -1 which is giving me a headache.
The method SHOULD exit after the print statement returning 1 but how can it continue to the 2nd return statement...I have an assignment due in few hours and I feel like the method is messing with me lol

Comment: The line is probably executing in one of the recursive calls that you are ignoring. Did you mean to return the result of `traverse` in the first two `if` statements?

Comment: i tried the return statement everywhere possible in that method including both those if statements. It executes everything but the return statement

Comment: Are you sure? Did you use `return traverse(i, root.left);` and `return traverse(i, root.right);`? If the print statement is executing, one of the recursive calls is obviously reaching that branch and will therefore return 1.

Comment: What did you find when you stepped through it with a debugger, anyway? You haven't mentioned that.

Comment: Try set a flag inside function and return it. Assign return value to a flag, when doing recursion call.

Comment: Thankyou everyone for the fast replies. I'm very grateful for it!

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're not returning the result that comes back from the left/right nodes:

```
public int traverse (int i, BNode root){ // Each child of a tree is a root of its subtree.

    if (root.left != null){
        int res = traverse(i, root.left);
        if (res != -1) return res;
    }
    if (root.right != null){
        int res = traverse(i, root.right);
        if (res != -1) return res;
    }
    if(root.index == i) {
        System.out.println(root.value);
        return 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: thank you! I'm horrible at recursions and tracing through recursive calls. I should learn to use debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine this tree:

```
    0:N1
      \
      1:N2
```

Let's see what the program will do:

First it calls `transverse(1, tree)`.
There is no left node so it moves on.
There is a right node so it calls `transverse(1, root)` on the right node.
There is no left node so it moves on.
There is no right node so it moves on.
The index is equal to the node index, so it returns 1.
Now let's zoom back out to the first call.
The index is not equal to the node index, so it moves on.
It returns -1.

Try this:

```
if (root.left != null) {
   if (traverse(i, root.left)) return 1;
}
if (root.right != null) {
   if (traverse(i, root.right)) return 1;
}

if(root.index == i) {
  System.out.println(root.value);
  return true;
}

return -1;
```

Comment: I tried that as well but it didn't work either. Can you maybe edit my code and post so i can better understand if i'm mistaking you...

Comment: Just replace `traverse(i, root.left);` with `return traverse(i, root.left);` and `traverse(i, root.right);` with `return traverse(i, root.right);`. Just try it again.

Comment: Your initial explanation was good, but not your followup advice.  Imagine a left node with a non-matching value and a right node with a matching value.  The code for the right node wouldn't be reached.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning the value from those recursive calls, so when one of those 2 recursive calls becomes "true" for:

```
if(root.index == i)
```

recursive method will return 1 but it will be ignored in the original caller method.

Answer (score 0):

Your key problem is in ignoring the return values of `traverse`.  It's good practice to evaluate your own node first, as well, so you don't waste the effort of needlessly traversing your child nodes.

```
public int traverse(int i, BNode root) {
    // Check self first so you don't waste effort traversing child nodes
    if (root.index == i) {
        System.out.println(root.value);
        return 1;
    }
    // If any child returns 1, we return 1
    if ((root.left != null) && (traverse(i, root.left)==1)) {
        return 1;
    }
    if ((root.right != null) && (traverse(i, root.right)==1)) {
        return 1;
    }
    // If neither child nor self returns 1, we return -1
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could always set a var to be -1 and when it reaches the third if it just changes that var then have return var because i do not belive that a Return statement in a if statement will work. But I have not done Java in a while so i am not 100% sure just something to try.

Comment: You can return from anywhere in a method, including inside an if statement. The real problem is probably ignoring the result of recursive calls.